# async property vs object property async template angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am reading an angular code and I see two ways to do the async in the angular templates.

1. `*ngIf="locals$ | async as locals"`
2. ```
   *ngIf="{
     locals: locals$ | async,
    } as objectData"
   ```

Are there advantages to using one way or another or what is the best way and why?

Comment: #2 is a hack - not recommended

Comment: #2 is definitely not a hack. Very useful even as it prevents the ngIf from being blocking (the object makes it always true-ish). It renders whatever is inside before the observable even emits, and also works if the result of the observable is false-ish.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find #1 to be the better choice of subscribing to observables in templates.

Why?

Well, if your template relies on the observable to succeed, then the content will display.

What happens if you used the second option, and something went wrong with the observable?

Well, the page may break depending on your error handling. Say your page expected content, but none was shown, so you see whitespace blocks where you expect content.